# cocos2d-iphone v3 (Chipmunk) : How to move a CCSprite left or right by applying impulse or force?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I decided to start learning game programming and i chose cocos2d V3 as my first 2d game engine.  As far as I understand, cocos2d-iphone v3 comes with chipmunk  as the physics engine.

I manage to create a portrait application that has a  Platform across left to right of the screen with an object (Box) on top of it.

Platform and Box are CCSprite with an attached CCPhysicsBody.

I wanted to push this box to the left when i touch the right side of the screen and push it to the right when i touch the left side of the screen. The box should not jump but just push left or right.

by looking from cocos2d v3 documentation, i found these methods : CCPhyicsBody

```
- (void)applyAngularImpulse:(CGFloat)impulse
- (void)applyForce:(CGPoint)force
- (void)applyForce:(CGPoint)force atLocalPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (void)applyForce:(CGPoint)force atWorldPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (void)applyImpulse:(CGPoint)impulse
- (void)applyImpulse:(CGPoint)impulse atLocalPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (void)applyImpulse:(CGPoint)impulse atWorldPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (void)applyTorque:(CGFloat)torque
```

and by using applyImpulse and passing the touch location CGPoint, i manage to make the box jump a little bit.  But my requirement is for my box to just move to the left or right without jumping.

Can someone please explain to me which method should i use? and what should be the parameter for the method?

**Thanks in advance for the help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and by using applyImpulse and passing the touch location CGPoint, i manage to make the box jump a little bit.

This is the problem. Using `applyImpulse` is the right way to do it, however **you need to provide the direction of the impulse as the CGPoint parameter**. You do not want to use the touch location as impulse direction.

To apply an impulse only to the left you need to create a new `CGPoint` for the impulse direction and the y value of this point should be 0:

`CGPoint impulse = ccp(-10.f, 0.f);`

Then pass this point to the method.